# how to control input variable in dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am struggling with below query:
   search..
| table .. AA_ID, BB_ID ..
| where (match(AA_ID, $AAID$) OR isnull($AAID$)) AND (match(BB_ID, $BBID$) OR isnull($BBID$))
.

$AAID$ and $BBID$ are from input variable in a dashboard I made and they are text type.
I want that when user didn't input or set the variables like 'all' or '*' then show all result, but it did not work like I expected.
There were many examples to control query's result by using where or search clause, 
but I haven't seen an example to control for input variable.

Please let me know, if you know anything or releated one.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added a `default` element to your `input`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I set * for it. But it doesn't look help.